# Is there a way to upgrade a machine which is using software raid and LVM to 12.10?

Tags: installation, 12.10, raid, lvm

I realize Ubuntu has dropped the alternate cd for 12.10, which broke this long-time user's heart. I *always* do a fresh install when upgrading, but I have software raid and LVM, and as far as I can tell only LVM is supported by the regular (only) cd now.

How can someone like me, using both, install 12.10?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also start out with the Server distribution, and simply do an immediate `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` after installation - this is actually how I do my desktop installations anyway, because the desktop distro won't do an LVM install.

Comment: This worked perfectly after manually installing the AMD Radeon drivers. Nice and easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Fortunately this is still possible using the netboot image that comes with a mini.iso containing the good old text-installer.

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/mini.iso

Comment: Just wondering - does the plain old `apt-get dist-upgrade` not work for such purposes in Ubuntu?

Comment: @MartinOrda of course it does, but the question was about "fresh install"...

Comment: The mini ISO is similar to Debian's netinst ISO. You should be able to install from a base system all the way up, including using existing volume groups and logical volumes.